# Passing data to child components in reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am working in reactjs application. I want to pass data to its child components. I am having Parent as parent component and Test1 and Test2 as its children components. Also I am having constant data in parent components. I want to pass same data in its all child components. How can I access this data in Test1 component
Code of parent

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react'; 
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {load} from 'redux/modules/viewlodging';
import Test1 from './Test1';
import Test2 from './Test2';
@connect(
state => ({data: state.viewlodging.data}),
dispatch => bindActionCreators({load}, dispatch))
export default class Viewlisting extends React.Component {
static propTypes = {
data: PropTypes.object,
load: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
render() {
const {data} = this.props;
return (
<div>
    <div className="row font14 relative">
        <div className="container relative">
            <div className="col-md-8">
                <div className="row details">
                    <{data.title}>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-4" >
                <Test1/>
                <Test2/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
);
}
}
```

In Test1

```
import React from 'react';
export default class Test1 extends React.Component {
 render() {
 return (
      <div className="summary-info">
          <div>From Test1</div>
      </div>
    );
 }
 }
```

How to access data in Test?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pass it as `props` and then access it with `this.props`.

In your parent add `props` which you want to pass :

```
<Test1 data={data}/>
```

in your child access to it with `this.props` :

```
<div className="summary-info">
   <div>From Test1 - this is from parent {this.props.data}</div>
</div>
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1505/)

Comment: after I passed data as per  ur answer. I am getting error "'data' is missing in props validation"

Comment: data is big object with me

Comment: @user1820017 Then is error in your data. Check what you get in your data.  Check the fiddle in updated answer. This is the right way to pass prop from parent to child. Try to put `console.log(data)` right below `const {data} = this.props ` and see what you get in the console.

Comment: Yes checked, Its logs object right below const {data}  = this.props, but now I do get error " Invalid prop `data` of type `string` supplied to `Test1`, expected `object`. Check the render method"

Comment: @user1820017 That will say that your data is a string and not an object.  In `static propTypes = {data: PropTypes.object}`  you say that data needs to be an object but it is an string. That is a warning not an error. Your app should work. Try with `<Test1 test="From parent"/>` and then in Test  `<div className="summary-info">{this.props.test}</div>` . Do you see **From parent**?

Comment: What you said above works perfect. I am calling api from load method in reducer for getting the data, so it will take while to get data. then I display that in parent container and wanted to show same data in its child components

Comment: @user1820017 That is how you pass props from parent to child. It's a bit difficult to see what the problem is when I do not see the data. Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Do I need static propTypes = {
      data: PropTypes.object
    } in Test1 component?

Comment: @user1820017 You can add it. But it won't change much. [Here is more info over PropTypes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) .